# Messaging between two classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, class

I have a basic question about fetching values through different classes.
I have a classA which fills an array (If i print it out it is not empty).
**LATER** in class B i want to load this Array: I call a function from class A which returns the Array of class A. But in class B if i call my new array then is it null. 
I am a bit confused, because i think i retain every value of the array, but its still null. I tried also a lot of different possibilities. I think its a basic OOP syntax fault i produce?!

//CLASS_A.h

```
@interface classA {

       NSMutableArray* buoyArray;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray * buoyArray;

-(NSMutableArray*)getArray:(NSMutableArray*)_array;
```

//CLASS_A.m

```
...        

-(NSMutableArray*)getArray:(NSMutableArray*)_array {
                _array=buoyArray;
                return _array;   
            }
```

//CLASS_B.h

```
#import "CLASS_A.h"


@class classA;
@interface classB ...

classA *mapSource;
NSMutableArray * buoyArray;
        }

@property(nonatomic,retain) classA *mapSource;
```

//CLASS_B.m

```
buoyArray=[mapSource getArray:buoyArray];
NSLog(@"%@",buoyArray);
```

Comment: Do you want each class to point to the same array, or should each have its own copy?

Comment: basically a copy of the array. i thought its a copy of an array in another class with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you you are making new object of class A by calling alloc so by init it reintialize all properties values for that instance.

What you need,if you are pushing class B over class A then, fetch existing class A object from stack, by using this line.

```
mapSource = (ClassA *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: [self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-2];
```

then call this

```
buoyArray=[mapSource getArray:buoyArray];
NSLog(@"%@",buoyArray);
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, but i have still the same problem :(